# CakePHP 3.1 - Get action return success for Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, cakephp

I'm trying to add data to database with ajax, but this is my first try of ajax, that's why I can't solve this problem.

I have add() action which checks if form is sent. If it is, it adds a record to database.

```
public function add()
{
    if ($this->request->is('ajax')) {
        Configure::write('debug', 0);
    }
    $this->loadComponent('RequestHandler');
    $this->loadModel('Galleries');

    $entity = $this->Galleries->newEntity();
    if ($this->request->is('post'))
    {
        /*$photos = $this->request->data['multiple_photos'];
        for ($i = 0; $i < count($photos); $i++) {
            $photo = [
                'name' => $this->request->data['multiple_photos'][$i]['name'],
                'type' => $this->request->data['multiple_photos'][$i]['type'],
                'tmp_name' => $this->request->data['multiple_photos'][$i]['tmp_name'],
                'error' => $this->request->data['multiple_photos'][$i]['error'],
                'size' => $this->request->data['multiple_photos'][$i]['size']
            ];
            echo "<pre>"; print_r($photo); echo "</pre>";
        }*/

        $data = [
            'id' => '',
            'thumb' => 'thuburl',
            'highres' => 'highresurl',
            'gal_id' => 1
        ];

        $entity = $this->Galleries->patchEntity($entity, $data);

        $this->Galleries->save($entity);
    }

    $this->set(compact('entity'));
    $this->viewBuilder()->layout(false);
    $this->render();
}
```

In my view:

```
<body>
<?php

    echo $this->Form->create($entity, ['type' => 'file', 'id' => 'formUpload', 'action' => 'add']);
    echo $this->Form->hidden('id', ['value' => '']);
    echo $this->Form->input('multiple_photos[]', ['type' => 'file', 'multiple' => 'true', 'label' => false]);
    echo $this->Form->hidden('thumb', ['value' => 'thumburl']);
    echo $this->Form->hidden('highres', ['value' => 'highresurl']);
    echo $this->Form->hidden('gal_id', ['value' => '1']);
    echo $this->Form->button('Wyslij', ['type' => 'submit']);
    echo $this->Form->end();

?>

<script>  
        $('#formUpload').submit(function() {

            var formData = $(this).serialize();
            var formUrl = $(this).attr('action');

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: formUrl,
                data: formData,
                success: function(data,textStatus,xhr) {
                    alert(data);
                },
                error: function(xhr,textStatus,error) {
                    alert(textStatus);
                }
            });
            return false;
        });
</script>

</body>
```

**What's the result?** It adds a record, so Ajax script works but I get "error" alert.

How to modify action or ajax script to get it working?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: what is response status returned from your script?

Comment: I get 404 Not Found status.

Comment: Got it working, just changed action to new one in controller. Now I just need to pass form data through the ajax request, cuz I get empty inputs.